# Database connection could not be established; Invalid data source name (Only with PDO)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

i'm trying to reach my new PGSQL database with PHP.
The problem is that i recieve the error given in the title. 
When i try to connect direct. It works, when i try to connect by PDO, it gives this error.

What i checked:

- PHP.ini. The required extensions are uncommented (both **php_pgsql.dll** and **php_pdo_pgsql.dll**)
- Made sure these two files are really in the PHP folder.
- Made sure the database,host,user,pass and port are correct by using simple script (shown belown)

  This is my config file for setting up the databases (i'm using 6 databases correctly. So i know the fault is not in that file)

  ```
  "Aeges":{
      "pdo_driver":"odbc",
      "user":"XXXX",
      "password":"XXXX",
      "database":"test",
      "host":"localhost",
      "port":1233
  },
  "Postgre":{
      "pdo_driver":"pgsql",
      "user":"XXXX",
      "password":"XXXX",
      "database":"ASN",
      "host":"localhost",
      "port":5432
  }
  etc..
  ```

This is my function to retrieve the information. I cleaned it up a bit to make it clear

```
public static function findAvailableASN()
{
    $Postgre = db\Factory::getInstance()->create('Postgre');
    $stmt = $Postgre->prepare("select * from asnregel.asnregel");
    if ($stmt->execute()) 
    {
        return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

/*  $connect = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=ASN user=XXXX password=XXXX");
    if(!$connect) {
        die("Error in connection: ".pg_last_error());
    }
    $sql = "select * from asnregel.asnregel";
    $result = pg_query($connect,$sql);
    if(!$result) {
        die("Error in sql query: ".pg_last_error());
    }

    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row[0].'<br/>';
        echo $row[1].'<br/>';
        echo $row[2].'<br/>';
        echo $row[3].'<br/>';
    }

    pg_free_result($result);
    pg_close($connect); */
}
```

So the problem is that the first part doesn't work (the part with PDO). While the commented (the part without PDO) does. Kind of weird right?

Somebody who can help me with this?

Comment: have you tried `$stmt = $Postgre->prepare("select * from asnregel")` ?

Comment: Is `db\Factory` a typo?

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: @wildplasser that doesn't work either. But i need asnregel.asnregel because of the schema. "select * from asnregel" doesn't work either in the 'simple test' while "select * from asnregel.asnregel" does

Comment: @Voitcus no, it is not a typo. It doesn't give me an error line. Just the pdo error: "Database connection could not be established: invalid data source name".

Comment: Ah. Often newcomers are confused by schema-qualified names, and use the username as a schemaname Not in your case, dus. BTW: the database *is* running and accepting connections on localhost ?

Comment: Off-topic question: what does \ operator mean in the factory class?

Comment: @wildplasser Yes it is running and accepting. The commented part echo's me the right results

Comment: @voitcus nice question. Can't answer it to be honest. yeah i'm new to this

Comment: Ah, ok, that's a namespace call, [refer here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Comment: Does direct connection work? I mean without a factory, eg. `$Postgre = new PDO('pgsql:user=XXX dbname=ASN password=XXX');`

Comment: Great gods, that works. But of course it's not the answer yet. But now  we're closer to. Thanks

Comment: So there is a problem with the factory class or your use of it, hard to tell without knowing anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Invalid data source name

The error message is pretty clear. Data source name is a DSN string you are using in the 
PDO constructor. And it appears to be invalid.

Thus, no need to check php.ini, php_pgsql.dll or password - all these errors have their distinct error messages to deal with.
So, all you need is to correct your DSN string. Print out your current DSN and compare it with canonical one, right from the manual page. For example, for pgsql the correct DSN format would be like

```
pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=testdb;user=bruce;password=mypass
```

while for all pther drivers the right format can be found in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php)